# Replace one word in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Personal
            [closeable] => 1
            [visible] => 1
          )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => My contracts
            [closeable] => 1
            [visible] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Info
            [closeable] => 1
            [visible] => 1
        )
)
```

I need to replace one word in the array - **My contracts** for something else.

My contracts will be always there, but the order may change, so I must check for the exact name and replace it.

I tried it via **str_replace($value, $replacement, $array);**

also via

```
$ar = array_replace($ar,
array_fill_keys(
    array_keys($ar, $value),
    $replacement
)
```

);

and finally:

```
array_map(function ($v) use ($value, $replacement) {
    return $v == $value ? $replacement : $v;
}, $arr);
```

Nothing worked. So how can I replace that one word?

Comment: You want to replace `My contracts` this value with something else right? and what does `The My contracts will be always there, but the order may change`, this mean?

Comment: it means that the name will be always My contracts but it may be on the second place in array or in 3rd place, etc.

Comment: what is `$value` in array_map ?

Comment: value should be My contracts. But it is already solved by the below answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($ar as &$item) {
    if ($item['title'] === 'My contracts') {
        $item['title'] = 'Some new value';
        // if you're sure that record will be met ONCE 
        // you can add `break;` to stop looping
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `array_walk`, you can approach as

```
$stringToFind    = 'My contracts';
$stringToReplace = 'REPLACMENT';
array_walk($arr, function(&$v,$k) use ($stringToFind,$stringToReplace){
 ($v['title'] == $stringToFind) ? ($v['title'] = $stringToReplace) : '';
});
```